# How to write the selenium webdriver script to verify that the login credentials are correct using assert?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, assert

For example,
Gmail Login->enter invalid username and invalid password and click login button,if i give invalid credentials it should display the error msg as "Invalid USername or Password".How to verify that the given credentials is correct or notand how to verify that i have logged in successfully??

Comment: hard code them in your test

Comment: Can you please give me  a sample code

Comment: .... seriously? String correctPassword = "correctPassword";

Answer (score 0):

Most systems require the user to change the password from time to time. It makes  Stultuske 's suggestion highly unstable because the credentials for a account **SURELY WILL** change. And even if your system do not require it, writing passwords is highly error-prone.

You are doing [Data-Driven Testing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/data_driven_testing.htm), so, you should store all your data in only place, not spread that across your test cases by hard-coding it.

A simple structure as a YAML file should be fine for you.
Most languages have libraries to work with this data. [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) and [Java](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml), e.g.

Let me give you an example; see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JoaoGFarias/581159a3478ed4e8f65e):
https://gist.github.com/JoaoGFarias/581159a3478ed4e8f65e

As you can see, if ever any password change, you only need to update the users.yml file, which is very simple.

Hard-coding is not a good thing in development and it's is not in Automation (because, let me tell you a secret: Automation is software development, same way - people often think it's not, but they are wrong).